# Finalizing bundle fails

Tags: transaction, iri-legacy-api, bundles, java

Finalizing the bundle fails, because the `ICurl` instance (`jota.pow.Kerl`) can't `absorb` due to the supplied trits not having the required length.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal length: 162
>
> at jota.pow.Kerl.absorb(Kerl.java:287)
> at jota.pow.Kerl.absorb(Kerl.java:9)
> at jota.model.Bundle.finalize(Bundle.java:118)

Below some example code that reproduces the error within my application.

Is there anything I should do different when creating bundles and transactions? How can I prevent this kind of error?

```
import jota.model.Bundle;
import jota.model.Transaction;
import jota.utils.SeedRandomGenerator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CreateBundle {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Transaction tx = new Transaction();
        tx.setValue(0);
        tx.setAddress("");
        tx.setTrunkTransaction("");
        tx.setBranchTransaction("");
        tx.setAttachmentTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        tx.setAttachmentTimestampLowerBound(0);
        tx.setAttachmentTimestampUpperBound(3_812_798_742_493L);
        //tx.setBundle(""); // set by finalize
        tx.setCurrentIndex(0);
        tx.setLastIndex(0);
        //tx.setHash("");
        tx.setObsoleteTag("");
        //tx.setPersistence(Boolean.TRUE);
        tx.setTag("APPLICATION_TAG");
        tx.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        String message = "DATA_TO_BE_SAVED_ON_TANGLE".replace('_', '9');
        String messageTrytes = message + new String(new char[2187 - message.length()]).replace('\0', '9');
        tx.setSignatureFragments(messageTrytes);

        System.out.println(tx);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(Arrays.asList(tx), 1);
        //bundle.normalizedBundle();

        bundle.finalize(null); // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal length: 162
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java library is quite picky about length of fields you set. In particular, the `address` has to be 81 trytes and both `tag` and `obsoleteTag` need to have 27 trytes. If the lengths are different (or these fields are empty), you get weird signing errors.

Changing the address to `"999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"` and the two tags to `"APPLICATION9TAG999999999999"` makes it work for me.

I made the experience that instead of building raw `Transaction` objects, it is often easier to create a new `Bundle`, add the number of transactions needed by `addEntry` and then tweaking the resulting transactions (if they need tweaking for my use case) before finalizing the bundle.

Comment: Thanks! Now the PoW fails... Do you have some resources? I've looked at `SignedCoordinator` in your private-iota-testnet repository and it helped a little.

Comment: When building your IOTA client, all you have to do is call `.localPoW(new PearlDiverLocalPoW())` before calling `.build()` and PoW will be done locally by CPU. Alternatively use a node that allows remote PoW.

Comment: If I only knew sooner :D I already implemented it manually. It was a hassle till I had the trunk and branch transactions in the bundle right. Thank you!